# Inheriting dialogs in Adobe CQ5

Tags: aem

I'm trying to implement a component dialog by inheriting a dialog of a base component. I'm having troubles with dialogs when used twice.

**BASE COMPONENT**

- dialog

  - text (name: "./text/content")

**OTHER COMPONENT**

- dialog

  - text (inherited from base)
  - text  (inherited from base)
  - settings
  - other

The problem with this is that it inherits the name as well and it doesn't look like you can override it. How can I make my jsp print out the two rich-text if they get inherited with the same name? Does CQ5 provide an index so that they can be referenced in the JSPs?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21293839/cq5-inheriting-extended-dialogs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your plan is to have two rich text areas in the dialog of components that inherit from the base, then you must include two rich text areas with unique names in the base component dialog.

Each input field of a dialog must have a unique name otherwise they will point to the same property path relative to the jcr:content node of the component when used on a page.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, Each input field of a dialog must have a unique name otherwise they will point to the same property path relative to the jcr:content node of the component when used on a page. Here, this will confuse the CRX while recognizing the textArea to be referred and the second one will not be referred.