# Is it possible to overwrite just a tab in the dialog box of a componnet that is inherited from another component

Tags: dialog, aem

I have a situation where I have two websites that need a similar component.  The only difference between the dialogs in the components is that one has an extra field on one of the tabs.  I would like to have the second component inherit from the first and just be able to add the additional field to the dialog.  I know how you can use the cqinclude xtype and path property to pull to separate the tab from the dialog, but from what I can tell, the path property has to be static.  Is there anyway to set the path property so that it is relative to the current component.  That way I will only have to put a modified version of the tab in the second component instead of having to copy over the entire dialog.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CQ5: Inheriting/Extended Dialogs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21293839/cq5-inheriting-extended-dialogs)

Comment: This is similar, but not exactly.  I'm trying to avoid having to copy the dialog into the second component and only having to put the modified tab there.  It seems like that's not possible though.